# Why docker exec command can launch shell with nologin user?

Tags: linux, docker, nologin

I have a nologin user for example `foo` in my `/etc/passwd` file:

```
foo:x:1010:1010::/home/foo:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

After I run this docker container, then I execute the command:

```
docker exec -it --user foo <container name> bash
```

It can actually login as `foo`, do I understand wrong? because from nologin man page, it says:

```
nologin displays a message that an account is not available and exits
non-zero.  It is intended as a replacement shell field to deny login
access to an account.
```

How can here docker exec with user foo work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker exec` is just starting a process in an existing namespace.  You aren’t logging into the container, just invoking a command owned by a certain user.  Docker doesn’t start the login process if you just tell it to run `bash`.

To get a fully working login process in docker you’d need to run some sort of login service, such as ssh, mgetty, gdm, or just plain`login foo`. In most cases, it would run through the PAM stack, and pam_unix would read the pwent and the login would fail to start a session.